# initialize array of object without default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, default-constructor

Is there a way to initialize an array of objects which don't have a default constructor?

```cpp
struct IndexAndSign {
    const int depth;
    const bool baseIsPositive;

    IndexAndSign(int depth, bool baseIsPositive)
      : depth(depth)
      , baseIsPositive(baseIsPositive) {}
};

void test() {
    auto arr = new IndexAndSign[size]; // error
}
```

Comment: OT: Please don't use `new[]` to create your array. If you know the size at compile-time and it will not change at run-time, use `std::array`, otherwise use `std::vector`.

Comment: No, but you can create an empty `std::vector<IndexAndSign>`, and then add constructed elements later.

Comment: how do you want to initialize them? Not via the default constructor, ok, but how else?

Comment: Well I wanna initialize them in a loop which iterates over the array

Comment: `class myClass { private: std::array<IndexAndSign,some_constant_size> allSignChangeEdges{}; }` creates and initializes `allSignChangeEdges` with all its memory set to 0 (because of the `{}` initializer)

Comment: Just wondering how will you get the data to initialize with if you have no constructore?

Comment: *Well I wanna initialize them in a loop which iterates over the array* -- As soon as you delcared the array (or instantiated using `new[]`), the initialization is done.  You can't go back and "undo" or "redo" the initialization.  Better to do what @BoP mentioned -- declare a vector, and add elements to an empty vector.

Comment: Quote: "**people who write class without a default constructor deserve what they get**. [...]. You never want to have a class with constructor and assignment but without default constructor." -- Alex Stepanov ("programming with components" lectures).

Comment: where are the parameters to the constructor come from when you use the loop? At some point they have to be known, and when they are know at the time you create the array then eg `allSignChangeEdges = new IndexAndSign[2]{{1,false},{2,true}};` just works. So the question remains, how do you want to initialize them?

Comment: Well the size ist user input dependent, so theres no way it's known at compile time

Comment: Just use `std::allocator` to allocate the array but not start lifetimes, Then use placement new in the for loop when you have the values to initialize the array's objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable if you are using c++17 or greater. You do this using `std::allocator::allocate` to allocate an array and start the lifetime of the array but not the array's objects. The array's objects are then initialized with a placement new in a for loop per OP's comment.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class IndexAndSign {
public:
    const int depth;
    const bool baseIsPositive;
    IndexAndSign(int depth, bool baseIsPositive) : depth(depth), baseIsPositive(baseIsPositive) {}
};

void test() {
    size_t size = 10;
    IndexAndSign* allSignChangeEdges;
    std::allocator<IndexAndSign> my_alloc;
    allSignChangeEdges = my_alloc.allocate(size);

    // demonstrate intitialization in a for loop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new(allSignChangeEdges + i) IndexAndSign(static_cast<int>(i), true);

    // show allSignChangeEdges[4].depth == 4
    std::cout << allSignChangeEdges[4].depth << '\n';

    // do stuff and cleanup 
    my_alloc.deallocate(allSignChangeEdges, size);
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Basically* you can't. As you've figured out, when you use

```
IndexAndSign* arr = new IndexAndSign[size];
```

C++ searches for the default (naked) constructor to allocate the correct amount of memory for your objects. But you can't provide naked constructor because of the initializer list due to the `const` members.

However, there are some loopholes:

1. The default newbie-hiting aswer is "use `std::vector`" eg.:

```cpp
std::vector<IndexAndSign> arr;
for(int i=size; i-->0;){
   int d=0; bool biP=true;              // or something
   arr.push_back(IndexAndSign(d, bIP));
}
```

However, there is a hidden problem with this solution: it uses the `move constructor` of your class. And if your class is a little complicated, the default move constructor provided by the compiler will be wrong (according to the [rule of n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

2. You can give a try to the [pointer to pointer concept](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-pointer-to-pointer-double-pointer/):

```cpp
IndexAndSign** arr = new IndexAndSign*[size];
for(int i=size; i-->0;){
     int d=0; bool biP=true;              // or something
     arr[i] = new IndexAndSign(d, bIP);
}
```

The backward of this solution, that if you want to access a member of your object, you have to use `->` instead of `.` eg.:

```cpp
std::cout << arr[0]->depth << std::endl;
```

Further reading is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-initialize-array-of-objects-with-parameterized-constructors-in-c/)